# Is it good to use exit() instead of fcloseall() for closing multiple files?

Tags: c, file, exit, manpage

The man page of `exit` says,

1. All open `stdio` streams are flushed and  closed. Files  created  by   `tmpfile` are removed.
2. Parameters of `exit` i.e `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are slightly more portable  (to non-UNIX  environments) than the use of 0 and some nonzero value like 1 or -1.  In particular, VMS uses a different convention.

The man page of `fcloseall` says,

1. The standard streams, `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are also closed.
2. The `fcloseall` function does not  lock  the  streams, so  it  is  not thread-safe.

Many online tutorials say that deallocating "all" resources of a given type is a programming error. They should be deallocated individually by the code that owns them or not at all.

So is it good to use `exit` instead of `fcloseall`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: yes, `exit()` is better.

Long answer:

It depends how you design your program. It is generally better to have each component clean up after itself, removing any temporary files and flushing buffers - this would be especially common for a C++ program where object destructors can handle this.

In that case you would use neither `exit()` nor `fcloseall()` - you'd have your components clean up after themselves then simply `return` from `main()`.

For a C program you might prefer to design it expecting that everything will be cleaned up automatically at exit by one of these functions. If you are considering using either, then `exit()` is a safer bet because it will do more: it will do what `fcloseall()` does, *plus* it will remove temporary files created with `tmpfile()`.

In addition, `fcloseall()` is a GNU extension which might affect the portability of your program.

**Perhaps more importantly**, these functions serve different purposes.

The purpose of `exit()` is to end your program.

The purpose of `fcloseall()` is to flush & close file descriptors, but not to end your program. It's perhaps most useful when you want to ensure you have closed all files (including stdin/stdout/stderr) before calling `exec` to start another process, without leaking any file descriptors into the new process that it will not expect and perhaps never close.

Answer (score 7):

The `fcloseall` function is a GNU extension. Using it makes your program less portable.

The `exit` function closes and flushes all stdio streams -- but it also terminates your program, which `fcloseall` doesn't do, so it's hardly a substitute.

There's probably no point in calling `fcloseall` if the program will continue to execute, and if it's just about to terminate anyway, `exit` will do the same thing.

The standard streams `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` generally don't need to be closed explicitly. It's perfectly all right to let the system close them for you when the program terminates. If you've opened any other streams, say by calling `fopen`, you should keep track of each such stream yourself, and close it explicitly when you're finished with it.